# Oracle Inactive Session holding LOCK, but with no command, and with an Active Transaction

Tags: oracle

I have a LOCK with an Inactive Session, that is not doing any Command, but it has an Active Transaction.
Why is the Transaction active?

Comment: Because pmon hasn't cleaned it up yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, Jeff Holt!

Comment: Please clarify in the title what the question is.

Comment: Hi cellepo, I am sorry about my question! I don't know how can I mark this as solved, but the first answer has already helped me in my search... Because I am new in DBA area and I was trying to understand all the relations a Session has with a Transaction and how could I say to my client, if the Session could be killed, because I even didn't know what it was doing, because its Transaction was Active but I couldn't find its SQL... But the tip about PMON helped me find some good informations already! =) Thank you all!